# "scripts": { "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1" },

Tags: node.js, backend

I am getting this same error every time i run "npm init" for my nodeJS backend. So, and even by some stack over flow answers I got to know that we can remove this error by replacing script.test with "mocha". But, when i previously installed npm. I doesn'thave this problem. I got it recently. Can anyone tell me why this error occurs?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: at what stage you are typing npm init? script tag is part of package.json, we run npm init to create package.json once its there we do not run npm init anymore

Comment: please share with us your workout, code snippets, error logs, or any useful information to help answer your question. Good luck 

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.